# Count white spaces to the left of a line in a text file using C++

Tags: c++, count, whitespace

I am just trying to count the number of white spaces to the LEFT of a line from a text file.
I have been using

```
count( line.begin(), line.end(), ' ' );
```

but obviously that includes ALL white spaces to the left, in between words and to the right.
So basically what I'm wanting it to do is once it hits a non-space character stop it from counting the white spaces.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: What is `line`? A `std::string`?

Comment: And are you looking for non-whitespace, or non-space?

Comment: @mmyers: I think that's a reasonable assumption.... though Nick Meyer's solution works even without member functions available on the type (so it works for vector too).

Comment: Sorry about that, I should have included that. It's a std::string, yes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming `line` is a `std::string`, how about:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <functional>

std::string::const_iterator firstNonSpace = std::find_if(line.begin(), line.end(),
   std::not1(std::ptr_fun<int,int>(isspace)));
int count = std::distance(line.begin(), firstNonSpace);
```

Comment: +1: Technically the only correct answer as it does real white space detection.

Comment: @Martin York: Yes. It returns the length of the string. `find_if` returns the ending iterator on failure.

Comment: Minor nitpicking: It would be more general to use a `std::string::const_iterator` here. Counting whitespaces doesn't modify the string and should be doable given a constant string. +1 anyway.

Comment: @sbi: This is why we really really need the `auto` keyword to act like it's C++0x :)

Comment: `std::not1(isspace)` doesn't compile. It should either `not1(ptr_fun<int,int>(isspace))` for `<cctype>` variant or `not1(bind2nd(ptr_fun(isspace<char>), locale("")))` for `<locale>`'s one.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian - A nice big upvote for your comment as that got this answer working correctly. And Thank you @Nick Meyer, your solution fits the needs of my program!

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian, thanks, I was sort of writing that off the top of my head.  Editing my answer.

Comment: @Billy: Absent of the new `auto` semantics, what we can do is to put this into a function template with the iterators being a template parameter. This or being pedantic. I'm pedantic. I`d even write `const std::string::const_iterator firstNonSpace = ...` and `const std::size_t count = ...`, just to be sure. (But then, I'd probably also put it into it's own function template nevertheless...)

Comment: @sbi: Yes yes I agree. Just saying it's a hell of a lot less verbose with `auto` :)

Answer (score 6):

How about

```
line.find_first_not_of(' ');
```

**EDIT:**
In case it's all spaces:

```
unsigned int n = line.find_first_not_of(' ');
if(n==s.npos)
    n = line.length();
```

Comment: You should be using line.npos instead of -1. That constant may be different depending on the platform you are using.

Answer (score 6):

Find the first non white space character.

```
std::string            test = "     plop";
std::string::size_type find = test.find_first_not_of(" \t");  // Note: std::string::npos returned when all space.
```

Technically not white space (as other characters are also white space).
Are you trying to count or strip white space?

If you are trying to strip white space then the stream operators do it automatically.

```
std::stringstream testStream(test);
std::string       word;

testStream >> word;  // white space stripped and first word loaded into 'word'
```

Comment: Just trying to count, not strip. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
int i = 0;
while ( isspace( line[i++] ) )
    ;
int whitespaceCnt = i-1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is line a string?

In that case you want to `std::string::find_first_not_of` to find the first non-whitespace, then use `std::count` on the remainder of the line like this:

```
std::string::size_type firstNonSpace = line.find_first_not_of(' ');
std::size_t result = std::count(line.begin()+(firstNonSpace==std::string::npos?0:firstNonSpace),line.end(),' ');
```

Comment: Don't you already know the amount of space when you've found the first non space? Why the call to `std::count`?